# Should I ask the same question again?

Tags: discussion, best-practice

A long time ago I wrote a question on ask ubuntu ( [How can I install another version of Ubuntu on my computer and then uninstall it without messing up my bootup process?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70415) ) and I never got a great answer. I accepted the answer I got because I appreciated the help.

Now I am wondering essentially the same question again--the only difference is if I asked the question now I wouldn't refer to the particular version of Ubuntu I used at the time.

At this point, should I re-ask the question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**If the question is different**, asking a new question makes sense. For example, if you asked a question, then the question turned into one special case of what you asked, and that got answered, and now you need help with a different special case or need a much more general answer, then you might want to post a new question. Just make clear how the new question is really different, so it doesn't get closed as a duplicate, and so that people know how their answers should be different from answers to your original question.

However, **if the question really isn't fundamentally different** (which seems to be what you're saying), then you shouldn't ask a new question. Instead:

- Unacccept the answer you accepted to your old question, so people know when they look at the question that it no longer has an accepted answer, and thus that you need help with it.

  - Looking at your question, it doesn't look like it currently has an accepted answer. Perhaps you already unaccepted. Or perhaps you had not previously *accepted* an answer (which is accomplished by clicking the gray check mark to the left of the answer), but had instead simply *upvoted* an answer. *You do not need to remove upvotes from answers to make clear you're still looking from an answer, and unless you've changed your mind about the answer being good or valuable, you should not remove an upvote (as an upvote indicates your belief that an answer is good or valuable).*
- **Edit** your old question to modify it as needed (in this case, at least to remove the reference to the old Ubuntu version). If possible, include information and insights you've obtained on the issue since then. Explain why you need help now (though don't go into too much detail about things that won't help people understand the problem), and why whatever answers exist so far, even if they may be valuable, are not sufficient for your needs. Make sure your question is tagged well too. Don't retag it just for the sake of retagging it, but when editing it (or at any other time), if you realize it has some inappropriate tags, or doesn't have some appropriate tags, correct that.

Unaccepting will make clear you're seeking answers again. Editing the question will bump it up higher on the list of questions. While you shouldn't edit a question just to bump it up, even when you have no improvement to make, it is a fundamental part of our site's design that editing a question increases its visibility. You've provided more information, so others will have the chance to see it.

You can also publicize the question in the same ways you can use for newer questions:

- Create [a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/set-bounties).
- Share a link to the question on social networks and/or microblogging services.
- Post about the question [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room). But don't just pop into chat, post a link, and leave. It is much better to instead post a bit of information about the question and what kind of help you're looking for, respond to questions and suggestions posted in chat, and stay in chat a while, so people feel like if they reply to you, you'll be there to hear them.

**Related: [FAQ: What if I don't get a good answer?](https://askubuntu.com/faq#bounty)**