# can I ask the same question again

Tags: discussion

for example I was looking for a question on "how to install eclipse". I found part of the solution in one question and the rest were distributed in different questions/fourms. Can I ask the same question however now am answering my self with a full answer that includes detailed information and pictures?

eclipse is an example :)

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I ask the same question again?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3722/should-i-ask-the-same-question-again)

Answer (score 7):

Why not just create a better answer to the one existing?

If in their core they ask the same then that makes them a duplicate. Make a better answer and post it in the existing one.

Answer (score 7):

No, that doesn't make sense. If the question is "How to install Eclipse" and you have a better answer then post it as a new answer or improve an existing answer.

The site would be worthless if we had dozens of iterations for each "How do I install foo"? scattered all over the place.